# Cross application transaction scoped persistence context injection

Tags: jpa-2.0, jboss7.x, ejb-3.1, ear, jboss-eap-6

I have a project broken down to 2 parts: persistence.jar, webapp.war. I don't package them in a single EAR, because I want to re-deploy webapp/run arquillian tests without re-deploying persistence for quick turnaround.

With this kind of setup, how can one use transaction scoped @PersistenceContext defined in persistence.jar from beans defined in webapp.war? Any other ways to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

There is no spec-defined way to achieve this.  The only option that comes to mind is to manage the transaction-scoped EntityManager yourself using TransactionSynchronizationRegistry.getResource, .putResource, and .registerInterposedSynchronization (basically, the same as what the JPA container normally does on you behalf).  It's also very likely that you'll need to somehow configure class loading in your application server to ensure that both applications have visibility to the same entity classes.